# CentOS 5.0 PCRE Unicode properties support solution

Tags: centos, pcre

I am getting the output of "pcretest -C"

```
 UTF-8 support
  **No Unicode properties support**
  Newline character is LF
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

I need to turn "Unicode properties support" on.

I tried with this(http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/) solution but while upgrading, getting conflicts with current PCRE and while installing newly showing dependency error.

Asking for another packages,when I tried to install (pcre-devel-6.61.fc5.remi.i386.rpm)devel packages,unfortunately getting

```
warning: pcre-devel-6.6-1.fc5.remi.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 00f97f56
error: Failed dependencies:
    pcre = 6.6-1.fc5.remi is needed by pcre-devel-6.6-1.fc5.remi.i386
```

What to do to make this settings up.
Thanks advance.

Comment: You're installing a Fedora Core 5 package onto a EL5 system?

Comment: I followed this artcile http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/

Comment: Have you actually read the article you linked to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if caveman is missing something, could you please help him out?

Comment: Please tell us the exactly step you did to cause the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you did following the steps you refer, do a reinstall of the package referenced in [here](http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/) (not the FC version), but instead of an upgrade, use:

```
rpm -ivh --replacepkgs pcre-6.6-2.7.x86_64.rpm
```

This will allow you to replace the packages that already exist on the system, since it is same version, but with different options enabled.

Comment: It works!to solve it had to rebuild the package with changed conf and installing it :)